# Is there a missing constructor for std::basic_istringstream in GCC 10.2, and if so, how do I construct one with a custom allocator?

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++20, stringstream, allocator

I have the following code:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

class CustomAllocator
{
public:
    CustomAllocator(const std::size_t sizeBytes,
                    void* const start)
    :
        m_sizeBytes(sizeBytes),
        m_usedBytes(0),
        m_start(start),
        m_current(start)
    {

    }

    void* Allocate(const std::size_t& numBytes,
                   const std::uintptr_t& alignment)
    {
        std::size_t space = m_sizeBytes - m_usedBytes;
        if(std::align(alignment, numBytes, m_current, space))
        {
            // the amount used for alignment
            m_usedBytes += (m_sizeBytes-m_usedBytes) - space;
            // the amount actually needed
            m_usedBytes += numBytes;

            void* address = m_current;

            m_current = reinterpret_cast<void*>(
                reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(m_current) + numBytes);

            return address;
        }
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }

    void Free(void* const ptr)
    {
        // do nothing in this Allocator, but other derived types may
    }

    void Clear()
    {
        m_current = m_start;
        m_usedBytes = 0;
    }

    std::size_t GetSize() const { return m_sizeBytes; }

    void* const GetStart() const { return m_start; }

protected:
    const std::size_t m_sizeBytes;
    std::size_t m_usedBytes;
    void* const m_start;
    void* m_current;
};
// many types derive from base CustomAllocator type

// allows for my custom allocators to be used in STL containers
template<typename T, typename Alloc>
class STLAdaptor
{
public:

    typedef T value_type;

    template<typename U>
    struct rebind
    {
        typedef STLAdaptor<U, Alloc> other;
    };

    STLAdaptor(Alloc& allocator)
    :
        m_allocator(allocator)
    {

    }

    template<typename U>
    STLAdaptor(const STLAdaptor<U, Alloc>& other) noexcept
    :
        m_allocator(other.m_allocator)
    {}

    [[nodiscard]] constexpr T* allocate(std::size_t n)
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>
            (m_allocator.Allocate(n * sizeof(T), alignof(T)));
    }

    constexpr void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t n)
    {
        m_allocator.Free(p);
    }

    std::size_t MaxAllocationSize() const
    {
        return m_allocator.GetSize();
    }

    bool operator==(const STLAdaptor<T,Alloc>& rhs)
    {
        return m_allocator.GetStart() == rhs.m_allocator.GetStart();
    }

    bool operator!=(const STLAdaptor<T,Alloc>& rhs)
    {
        return !(*this == rhs);
    }

    Alloc& m_allocator;
};

int main()
{
    const std::size_t memSize = 10000000;
    void* mem = std::malloc(memSize);

    CustomAllocator customAlloc(memSize, mem);

    std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
        STLAdaptor<char, CustomAllocator>>
        myString(customAlloc);

    myString = "something something";

    std::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>,
        STLAdaptor<char, CustomAllocator>>
        iss(myString, std::ios_base::in, customAlloc);

    std::free(mem);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with GCC 10.2 `-Wall -fexceptions -std=c++2a -g` I get the following errors:

```
||=== Build: Debug in CPPTESTS (compiler: Mingw-8.1.0 32bit) ===|
C:\CPPTESTS\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\CPPTESTS\main.cpp|136|error: no matching function for call to 'std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, STLAdaptor<char, CustomAllocator> >::basic_istringstream(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, STLAdaptor<char, CustomAllocator> >&, const openmode&, CustomAllocator&)'|
C:\MSYS2-32\mingw32\include\c++\10.2.0\sstream|477|note: candidate: 'std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_istringstream(std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = STLAdaptor<char, CustomAllocator>]'|
C:\MSYS2-32\mingw32\include\c++\10.2.0\sstream|477|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided|
C:\MSYS2-32\mingw32\include\c++\10.2.0\sstream|460|note: candidate: 'std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_istringstream(const __string_type&, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = STLAdaptor<char, CustomAllocator>; std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::__string_type = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, STLAdaptor<char, CustomAllocator> >; std::ios_base::openmode = std::ios_base::openmode]'|
C:\MSYS2-32\mingw32\include\c++\10.2.0\sstream|460|note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided|
C:\MSYS2-32\mingw32\include\c++\10.2.0\sstream|442|note: candidate: 'std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_istringstream(std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = STLAdaptor<char, CustomAllocator>; std::ios_base::openmode = std::ios_base::openmode]'|
C:\MSYS2-32\mingw32\include\c++\10.2.0\sstream|442|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided|
C:\MSYS2-32\mingw32\include\c++\10.2.0\sstream|425|note: candidate: 'std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_istringstream() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = STLAdaptor<char, CustomAllocator>]'|
C:\MSYS2-32\mingw32\include\c++\10.2.0\sstream|425|note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 3 provided|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Looking at the code for `std::basic_istringstream` in `<sstream>` it appears that constructors 5 to 9 from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream/basic_istringstream don't exist, which certainly explains my errors.

But then if so, how on earth do I construct such an object with a stateful custom allocator?

Comment: Yes @TedLyngmo I'm sure you don't know the answer to the question. I have provided a minimal reproducible example as demostrated by your link to copy-pasting into godbolt.

Comment: Thanks @TedLyngmo, I'm sure there's other questions that you should make sure people know you personally haven't got answers to.

Comment: As it happens - I tend to help people to make their questions answerable more than I answer them myself.

Comment: I did that to _not_ make the comments up for deletion. It was a favor. Please ...

Comment: [No errors here, only warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/M1bhTc).  Did you use the `-std=c++2a` switch when you compiled the code?

Comment: Yes, What compilation flags did you use?  What version of the standard library are you using?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie if you use GCC 10.2 you'll see the errors

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've edited the question to show the flags used. Yes `-std=c++2a` was used

Comment: Looks like it just hasn't been implemented yet.  works on trunk [here](https://godbolt.org/z/KK6Y4W) but not [with 10.2](https://godbolt.org/z/8nzWKz).  C++20 hasn't actually been published so it's not too surprising.

Comment: That's the risk of attempting to use features for a version of C++ that has yet to be officially standardized.

Comment: Thanks PaulMcKenzie and NathanOliver, looks like I'm too overzealous in C++20 usage. If you guys want to post an answer to use the latest trunk I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that version gcc 10.2 does not support the C++20 constructors for [std::basic_istringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream/basic_istringstream).

Until C++20 becomes officially standardized, you could use the gcc trunk after 10.2, which has support for the C++20 constructors, and thus compiles the code with no errors:

[Live godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/M1bhTc)